# Is there a way I continue on with a website while a file is being uploaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

**Background:**

I am working on an undergrad research project for my CS department. The project is a website for the biology department and a key feature is that the biology students are able to upload their own `.xml` files and then a *model is built for them on the server side using Matlab.

The front end is in an ASP.NET, javascript and C# environment. My little association with this project is all the knowledge I have of these systems, tools and languages.

**Question:**

The `.xml` files I mentioned earlier can take hours to upload and build. My professor wants the user to be able to continue on with the page using models that are already completed while the new model is sent to the background and the user receives an email when it is completed. I've found material for sending the email, but not for continuing with the page.

I heard something about using AJAX to load a page?

Comment: To clarify, you say it "can take hours to upload and build". I assume the upload part of that is very quick, and the build takes a long time?

Comment: Yes. And the way it is set up now a little circle pops up and spins the entire time it is building.

Answer (score 1):

Place a file upload control on your page

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>
```

Build an http handler to handle the file upload:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        HttpPostedFile fileToUpload = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
        string pathToSave = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/")
                            + fileToUpload.FileName;
        fileToUpload.SaveAs(pathToSave);

        //Process file
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look if you can integrate an upload plugin like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) into the project(needs jQuery).

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").uploadify(
     {
       'swf': 'Scripts/uploadify.swf',
       'uploader': 'Handler.ashx',
       'auto': true,
      'buttonText': 'Select File(s)'
     });
});
</script>
```

If you cannot do this, you need to understand how ajax works

Ajax normally uses XMLHttpRequest, which does not allow you encode and send local files to a server.
You could, either use a Flash swf to handle the uploading on the same page, or to use a form that has a target of an invisible 1x1 iframe.

I found the code posted on this blog about [file uploads in asp.net](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/07/asynchronous-file-upload-jquery-uploadify-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think having a small i-frame open up, which will actually do the upload, will let your current page continue working.

So on your current page, you ask for file location and file name and all, then open a new page in an i-frame. Let that i-frame know the source file/folder, destination file/folder, and let it work in the background. So now your current page is free to continue its work.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a headless Java Upload Applet.
Load the file transfer applet in an iFrame, let the user initiate the file transfer and when a user wants to browse the rest of the website, just don't reload the iFrame containing the Java Applet (which will be uploading the file). After the transfer is complete, do a JAvaScript call to close the iframe.

The following example uses a Java Applet by FileCatalyst, but the idea will be practically with any other Java FTP Applet or ActiveX

```
<script>
    var browsePath = "";

    function browseAndAdd() {
      browsePath = document.FileCatalyst.browseLive(true);
   }

    function upload() {
    document.FileCatalyst.uploadLive();
   }

   function clearQueue() {
     document.FileCatalyst.clearQueue();
   }
 </script>

 <!--Uses onClick for demonstration only-->
 <form id="uploadform">
  <!--Launch a browse dialog and add the selected file to the queue-->
 <input type=button onClick="javascript:browseAndAdd();" value="Browse and Add to Queue" />

    <!-- Force upload of whatever is currently found in the transfer queue -->
    <input type=button onClick="javascript:upload();" value="Upload">

   <!-- Clear transfer queue (can be called only if no transfers are in progress) -->
    <input type=button onClick="javascript:clearQueue();" value="Clear Queue">
   </form>
```

Apologies for lack of indentation, I find the stackoverflow markup for inserting code snipets not very user friendly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up somekind of asynchronous processing ideally. Personally I like to use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) and RabbitMQ for my async and messaging.